# TinyMCE conflicts with Supersleight

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am using Supersleight to make images transparent in IE6. I am also using TinyMCE for rich text areas. However, when I activate TinyMCE with the tinyMCE.init method, supersleight stops working. Has anyone else experienced this and maybe found a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are having a conflict. A simple solution is move your onload function to supersleight.js

```
init: function() { 
            addLoadEvent(fnLoadPngs);
            addLoadEvent(initForm);
        },
```

See: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=197867 for a post that explains this.